# how to Put add in our android application

Tags: java, android

I have created an application for admob, but I am getting an error. I found an example from Google and I have tried it, but there is a problem when I'm launching the application .

I'm using Android 2.2 API 8.
I am able to launch the application, but this block is causing an error.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

If I change this to

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

then I am able to launch the application, but there is an error coming on our add field.

```
you must have adactivity declare in Android Manfiest.xml with config change
```

Due to this I am not able to show google adds in our application.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - AdActivity.java

package com.android.ads;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class AdsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        AdView adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        re.setTesting(true);
        re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
        adview.loadAd(re);
    }
}

 - main.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

     <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="Your adunit ID" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>    
</LinearLayout>

Remember Put GoogleMapAdmobSdk.jar after creating libs folder for Configure build path 


Create the attrs.xml in the Values folder

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
      <attr name="adSize">
          <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
          <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
          <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
          <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
      </attr>
      <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>

 - AndroidManifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.ads"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AdsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    </application>

</manifest>


Your work is done buddy............
```

Comment: i m trying to do This posted Example once i ll be implement i will give you feed back

Comment: forcly closed when i add   <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="Your adunit ID" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

Comment: can u send me implemented zip file so that i can import and put it

Comment: Have you added ads:adUnitId="Your adunit ID" means your admob publish key paste your key over here if not??

Comment: if u don't mind kindly send implemented in anilat87@gmail.com

Comment: i dont have Publish key can u send me ur publish key

Comment: i have registers today once i ll get key then i ll give u

Comment: I have sent the code plz check your email generate the publish key and add the Ads in the layout ads:adUnitId="Paste your adunit ID(Publish key)" here...

Comment: Thankyou i m importing and i m telling u

Comment: It's the same code which I have pasted over here as answer so no worries...Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just have to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals) tutorial.

And escpecially your problem should be about this lines:

> The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires Android 1.5 or later. Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).

that means that minSDK can be down to 1.5 but you have to compile on 3.2 at least.

Answer (score 0):

from AdMob documentation

you need to add the entire activity tag to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals

Comment: rror: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
 screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

Comment: This error is coming when i put android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

Comment: That's strange, because all my apps using admob compiles fine with this tag in AndroidManifest.xml. 
Did you put the entire tag, or just copied the part with `android:configChanges="..."` to your existing activity tag?

Comment: OK, my bad. Target SDK must be set to android-13 or above, which is Android 3.2 before all the configChanges flag can be used.  Marioo O. Lenci's answer is correct.